# Getting c# function value and displaying in html table

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to get a string returned by a c# function and display it in an html table I have created. I have an asp.net button which calls a c# button_onclick function:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

I also have an html table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th><span>Col2</span></th>
    <th>Col3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Random1</td>
    <td>Random2</td>
    <td>Random3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have a c# function linked to the button click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //not sure what to do here. I want to call a separate function which will return
  //an array of 3 strings which would go in place of Random1, Random2, Random3 in the table
}
```

The reason I'm not using an asp.net table is because I want to use the css for my html table (let me know if there's a way to incorporate that css into an asp.net table, or if my logic is completely off here).
Any idea how I should approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to put an `asp:Label` into your table

```
<tr>
    <td><asp:label id="lblRandom1" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:label id="lblRandom2" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:label id="lblRandom3" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
```

and populate those from within `Button1_Click`

Also, you can use css with an asp table by setting the `CssClass` attribute, e.g.

```
<asp:Table CssClass="classname" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your `<td>` runat server which would make it a [HtmlTableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wsbhse3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<td runat="server" id="td1">Random1</td>
<td runat="server" id="td2">Random2</td>
<td runat="server" id="td3">Random3</td>
```

So you can access them in your click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     td1.InnerText ="Random1";
     td2.InnerText ="Random2";
     td3.InnerText ="Random3";
}
```

because the HtmlTableCell is subclass of [HtmlContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which provides properties to set or get the Innertext and InnerHtml which in turn will be rendered in the `<td>`